# How to manipulate audio file to hear only single side?

Tags: java, audio

I have some issue. I use Java sound API https://web.mit.edu/java_v1.5.0_22/distrib/share/docs/guide/sound/programmer_guide/contents.html

Then I have two same duration audio files.

**Question:** How to merge two audio files a parallel?

**In other words. as a result, New merged file should hear left side to first audio file and hear right side to second audio file.** 
Help me!?
I'm confusing

Thanks for all!

Comment: Show some code that you tried

Comment: @gpasch I cannpt show you. Because I didn't start coding. I can't find method solving that problem.